# Calculation of Current Fiscal Period

Tags: fiscal-periods

How do I calculate the fiscal period based on today's date?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please **[edit]** this post be as specific as possible about what you are trying to achieve. As written, there are several possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the FiscalYearSettings object. The below query will give you the year record with the StartDate as the start of the fiscal year and EndDate as end of fiscal year.

```
SELECT EndDate, IsStandardYear, Name, PeriodId, StartDate 
  FROM FiscalYearSettings 
 WHERE EndDate >= TODAY 
   AND StartDate <= TODAY
```

Once you get that, keep adding 3 months to Start date till the difference between Startdate and TODAY < 90 Days. Similarly subtract 3 months from EndDate till the difference is < 90 days. Those 2 dates would be your fiscal quarter start and end date.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some Fiscal Period utilities I had laying around....Feel free to modify them as you see fit... All you need is a date which could be today or any other date

```
/*********************************************
*
* Fiscal Quarter
*
**********************************************/

public static Date dateToday;

/*
    Gets the FQ for the last 15 months including today
    Returning the results with the most recent quarter
 */
@TestVisible private static Period[] fiscalQuarters {
    get {
        if (fiscalQuarters == null) {
            Date earliestDate = dateToday.addMonths(-15).toStartOfMonth();
            fiscalQuarters = [
                    Select StartDate, EndDate, FullyQualifiedLabel, Number
                    From Period
                    Where type = 'Quarter' AND StartDate >= :earliestDate AND StartDate <= :dateToday
                    Order By EndDate ASC
            ];
        }
        return fiscalQuarters;
    }
    set;
}

public static integer getFiscalQuarter(Integer year, String month, Date asOfDate) {
    return (Integer) getCurrentPeriod(year, month, false, asOfDate);
}

public static Object getCurrentPeriod(Integer year, String month, boolean returnPeriod, Date asOfDate) {
    Date tmp = Date.newInstance(year, monthAsInteger(month), 01);
    dateToday = asOfDate;

    for (Period p : fiscalQuarters) {
        if (p.StartDate <= tmp && p.EndDate >= tmp)
            if (returnPeriod) {
                return p;
            }
            else {
                return p.number;
            }
    }
    return null;

}

private static Integer monthsLeftInQuarter {
    get {
        return monthsLeftInQuarter;
    }
    set;
}

public static Integer monthsLeftInCurrentQuarter(Date currentMonth) {

    if (monthsLeftInQuarter == null) {
        Period currentQuarter = [
                Select StartDate, EndDate, FullyQualifiedLabel, Number
                From Period
                Where type = 'Quarter' AND StartDate <= :currentMonth AND EndDate >= :currentMonth
        ];

        monthsLeftInQuarter = currentMonth.addMonths(-1).monthsBetween(currentQuarter.EndDate);
    }
    return monthsLeftInQuarter;

}

/*
    The current fiscal period
 */
public static Period[] getfiscalPeriod(Date calculationDate) {
    return [
            Select
                    StartDate,
                    EndDate,
                    FullyQualifiedLabel,
                    Number
            From Period
            Where type = 'Quarter'
            AND StartDate <= :calculationDate
            AND EndDate >= :calculationDate
    ];

}
```

**Note:** You may need to infer some of the misc utility function called from the methods above....